# glibc detected when using dynamic array in C on a linux OS

Tags: arrays, dynamic, malloc, glibc, fread

I am trying to declare a dynamic array so that it can read and store specifically 100 bytes of contents into the char *buffer. It works well when it is the fread function is has a size_t nmemb of is a small amount, like 10. But when I set it higher it displays some of the contents but gives me a glibc detected error.

This is how it works if in the fread function I set it to a small number

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

FILE *fp;
int num;   
char *buffer;
buffer=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*num);
memset(buffer.0,sizeof(char)*num);
   /* Open file for reading */
   fp = fopen("hello.txt", "r");

   /* Read and display data */
   fread(buffer, 1, 10, fp);
   printf("%s\n", buffer);
free(buffer);
   fclose(fp);

   return(0);
}

/***************   Ouput   *****************/

travis@ubuntu:~$ g++ -o fileread2 fileread2.c

travis@ubuntu:~$ ./fileread2

asdkfjasdk
```

This is what happens when I change it the 3rd arg in fread to a 100:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
        {   
FILE *fp;
int num;   
char *buffer;
buffer=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*num);
memset(buffer.0,sizeof(char)*num);

           /* Open file for reading */
           fp = fopen("hello.txt", "r");

           /* Read and display data */
           fread(buffer, 1, 100, fp);/*This is all I changed*/
           printf("%s\n", buffer);
free(buffer);
           fclose(fp);

           return(0);
        }

/*************    Output   ********************/

travis@ubuntu:~$ g++ -o fileread2 fileread2.c

travis@ubuntu:~$ ./fileread2

asdkfjasdk;ljfkadsljck;lasm
asdkjdasfkja�s;kljfa
sdfksadjf;kljads;lkjads;lkjfadslkja
dsasdkfj;dsjf;a�
*** glibc detected *** ./fileread2: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000d88010 ***

======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7fb2aa586b96]
./fileread2[0x4007c8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7fb2aa52976d]
./fileread2[0x400659]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 785332                             /home/travis/fileread2
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 07:00 785332                             /home/travis/fileread2
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 07:00 785332                             /home/travis/fileread2
00d88000-00da9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fb2aa2f0000-7fb2aa305000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 265977                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fb2aa305000-7fb2aa504000 ---p 00015000 07:00 265977                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fb2aa504000-7fb2aa505000 r--p 00014000 07:00 265977                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fb2aa505000-7fb2aa506000 rw-p 00015000 07:00 265977                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fb2aa508000-7fb2aa6bd000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 281111                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7fb2aa6bd000-7fb2aa8bd000 ---p 001b5000 07:00 281111                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7fb2aa8bd000-7fb2aa8c1000 r--p 001b5000 07:00 281111                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7fb2aa8c1000-7fb2aa8c3000 rw-p 001b9000 07:00 281111                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7fb2aa8c3000-7fb2aa8c8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb2aa8c8000-7fb2aa8ea000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 281123                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fb2aaae6000-7fb2aaaea000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb2aaaea000-7fb2aaaeb000 r--p 00022000 07:00 281123                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fb2aaaeb000-7fb2aaaed000 rw-p 00023000 07:00 281123                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fb2aaaed000-7fb2aaaf1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffdf9a2000-7fffdf9c3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffdfa00000-7fffdfa02000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)

/*****        End of Output      ******/
```

Can someone help me out on this please?? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `malloc` with the product of `num` and `sizeof(char)`. The value `num` is not initialized to anything. So you are allocating a random amount of memory when you call `malloc`. You should set `num` equal to the number of bytes you intend to read in or greater. I suggest modifying your code along these lines

```
num = 100;
buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*num))
int err = fread(buffer,sizeof(char),num,fp);
```

In this way you will not read in more data than is available in `buffer`. Also, you should check the return values of `fread` and `malloc` for possible errors. `malloc` can return the NULL pointer on error, and `fread` can return zero. You'll need to use `ferror` to get the exact error.

Comment: Also note that `sizeof(char)` is always 1, and is *useless noise*.